# Azure WebJob - No functions found. Try making job classes public and methods public static

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I'm using an Azure WebJob, but now I get the following error message:

No functions found. Try making job classes public and methods public static.

My code is so simple:

```
static void Main()
{
    var host = new JobHost(); 
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
public static async Task BlobTrigger(
    [BlobTrigger("test/{name}")] Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob input,
    TextWriter log)
{
    //code
}
```

Also, I create a zip file from my debug folder and upload it, and the job is configure to run continuously.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

so sorry, the error is so simple, I added the access public to the class and it's fine (I'm using the final version of web jobs here), but I have some jobs with the webjobs prerelease and the public it's not necessary.

Thanks to all, regards.

Comment: Hey Julito, Could you tell me how you fixed this issue? I'm getting the same thing but I don't understand what you mean by "I added the access public to the class"

Comment: Hi hjavaher, I only add the modifier access public to my class adn ready, the webjob is fine, so my code looks like: public class myclass { // the same code that I put in the question}

Comment: Hitting this as well, but making everything public does nothing, wondering if it's related to async / await

Comment: make your Program class and Main method public.

Comment: It did not help me to set the Program class and Main method public.